# "Error during sbt execution: No Scala version specified or detected" with SBT from Homebrew

Tags: scala, sbt, homebrew

I have installed Scala **2.10.3** and SBT **0.13.1**. When I execute SBT following [Hello, World from the SBT documentation](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.1/docs/Getting-Started/Hello.html) I get the following error message:

> "Error during sbt execution: No Scala version specified or detected"

I've tried to add a `build.sbt` file with the `scalaVersion` but the error keeps showing up.

Please advise.

I've just downgraded sbt to 0.12.3 and it works ... so what's wrong with 0.13.X ?

Comment: You don't need to install Scala to use SBT (so we don't have to think about it while helping you out). What does `build.sbt` look like? Could you ensure you've only got `build.sbt` in the project? That's all you really need (and even the file's not needed) - hence the `simple` part.

Comment: name := "hello-sbt"

organization := "org.example"

scalaVersion := "2.10.3"

version := "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT" (with a blank line between each statement)

Comment: Can you run `sbt about` in an empty directory? What's the output? You really need no files to run `sbt`.

Comment: I got the same problem when upgrading from 0.13.0 to 0.13.1 and created an issue: https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/1117

Answer (score 6):

Its not an issue with the upgrade of 0.13.* version. Its the repository cache thats causing the issue. There are possibilities where you have broken / no ivys (when only the jar is downloaded through maven repo) for the sbt jars in your cache.

Once upgraded remove your ivy repo cache (or rename the folder) and remove the .sbt/boot folder (removing this will enable to start from the scratch)

Edit your ./sbt/repositories file and provide preference to the ivy repositories. If you are using proxy repositories which includes both ivy and maven style artifacts, the add it as below

```
[repositories]

local

maven-local

maven-central-ivy: http://<repository url>, [organization]/[module]/(scala_[scalaVersion]/)(sbt_[sbtVersion]/)[revision]/[type]s/[artifact](-[classifier]).[ext]

maven-central: http://<repository url>
```

This will enable especially (org.scala-sbt/sbt/*) to be download with the Ivys xml from where the version / revision and dependencies are picked up for the builds. If only the jar is downloaded from "maven-central", then the error occurs.

Answer (score 1):

It is the problem of IDE you are using specially the scala plugin in it. 
You can get ride of this just go to the folder where the build.sbt is created. Delete the "project" folder and open cmd, run "sbt" command on the folder, a new project folder will be created. Now you can open that in IDE. 
It may be that you may find some problem very first in ide, if you build the project once , all the problems will go away.

Answer (score 0):

I did exactly what @Gopi proposed but this is my repositories file content:

```
[repositories]

  local
  jcenter: https://jcenter.bintray.com/
  maven-central
  typesafe-ivy-releases: https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/, [organization]/[module]/[revision]/[type]s/[artifact](-[classifier]).[ext], bootOnly
  sbt-ivy-snapshots: https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/ivy-snapshots/, [organization]/[module]/[revision]/[type]s/[artifact](-[classifier]).[ext], bootOnly
```

My SBT Version: 1.1.1
java version 1.8
Windows 10

Hope that helps,
BR. Paul

Answer (score -1):

I've also installed both Scala and SBT on my machine through homebrew and can just run the given simple hello example, so i guess you did something wrong :-)

Please provide a bit more diagnostics, for example:

What is the output of both commands 'which sbt' and 'which scala'?
You should see the results as below:

```
$ which scala
/usr/local/bin/scala

$ which sbt
/usr/local/bin/sbt

$ ls -laF /usr/local/bin/sbt
lrwxr-xr-x  1 rjk  admin  28 Feb  9 13:32 /usr/local/bin/sbt@ -> ../Cellar/sbt/0.13.1/bin/sbt

$ ls -laF /usr/local/bin/scala
lrwxr-xr-x  1 rjk  admin  32 Feb  9 13:38 /usr/local/bin/scala@ -> ../Cellar/scala/2.10.3/bin/scala
```

And given the directory where you ran the example code from, is it completely empty besides the hw.scala example? Or did you also add the build.sbt or project/build.properties? If that's the case it would be wise to also list that here to spot any problems with them.

Comment: You don't need Scala for SBT. It will take care of it so you don't have to.

Comment: I just experienced that indeed by just removing Scala to see if it would give the same error the topic author stated :-)

Comment: here are the result of the commands :  which scala  
/usr/local/bin/scala  
which sbt  
/usr/local/bin/sbt
ls -laF /usr/local/bin/sbt
lrwxr-xr-x /usr/local/bin/sbt@ -> ../Cellar/sbt/0.13.0/bin/sbt
ls -laF /usr/local/bin/scala
lrwxr-xr-x /usr/local/bin/scala@ -> ../Cellar/scala/2.10.3/bin/scala

Comment: The directory containing the hw.scala empty besides the hw.scala file. I've tried to add a build.sbt file but it doesn't fix the problem.