# SBT - "No Scala version specified or detected" using mirrored repository behind firewall

Tags: scala, sbt, ivy

I am trying to get SBT working on Windows behind a corporate firewall but have run into a road block.

I have a very barebones SBT setup right now:

```
c:\dev\workspace\manualsbt>dir
 Volume in drive C is OSDisk
 Volume Serial Number is XXXX-YYYY

 Directory of c:\dev\workspace\manualsbt

11/23/2015  02:26 PM    <DIR>          .
11/23/2015  02:26 PM    <DIR>          ..
11/23/2015  02:27 PM               143 build.sbt
11/23/2015  02:25 PM    <DIR>          src
               1 File(s)            143 bytes
               3 Dir(s)  90,971,619,328 bytes free
```

The build.sbt file is also simple:

```
name := "manualsbt" # project name

version := "0.0.0" #project version

scalaVersion := "2.10.4" #the current scala version of the project
```

I set up my repositories file to go against my company's internal mirror:

```
[repositories]
  local
  xxxivy: https://repo.xxxxxxxx.net/maven/content/repositories/XXXX-IVY-HOSTED-OS/
  nexus: https://repo.xxxxxxxx.net/maven/content/groups/xxxx-public/
```

However, when I run 'sbt', I get an error:

```
Getting org.fusesource.jansi jansi 1.11 ...
downloading https://repo.xxxxxxxx.net/maven/content/groups/xxxx-public/org/fusesource/jansi/jansi/1.11/jansi-1.11.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.11!jansi.jar (908ms)
:: retrieving :: org.scala-sbt#boot-jansi
        confs: [default]
        1 artifacts copied, 0 already retrieved (111kB/37ms)
Getting org.scala-sbt sbt 0.13.5 ...
downloading https://repo.xxxxxxxx.net/maven/content/repositories/xxxx-IVY-HOSTED-OS/org/scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.5/sbt-0.13.5.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.13.5!sbt.jar (418ms)
:: retrieving :: org.scala-sbt#boot-app
        confs: [default]
        1 artifacts copied, 0 already retrieved (20kB/20ms)
Error during sbt execution: No Scala version specified or detected
```

I tried the solutions at ["Error during sbt execution: No Scala version specified or detected" with SBT from Homebrew](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21658279/error-during-sbt-execution-no-scala-version-specified-or-detected-with-sbt-fr) and several other pages but have not had any luck.

I have had this issue with both SBT 0.13.5 and 0.13.9. Please let me know whether I am missing anything.

Edit: This is what .sbt\boot\update.log looks like:

```
setting 'ivy.default.settings.dir' to 'jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/sbt/bin/sbt-launch.jar!/org/apache/ivy/core/settings'
setting 'ivy.basedir' to 'C:\dev\workspace\manualsbt\.'
setting 'ivy.default.conf.dir' to 'jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/sbt/bin/sbt-launch.jar!/org/apache/ivy/core/settings'
impossible to define new type: class not found: org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.SshResolver in [] nor Ivy classloader
impossible to define new type: class not found: org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.VsftpResolver in [] nor Ivy classloader
impossible to define new type: class not found: org.apache.ivy.plugins.version.PatternVersionMatcher in [] nor Ivy classloader
impossible to define new type: class not found: org.apache.ivy.plugins.trigger.LogTrigger in [] nor Ivy classloader
impossible to define new type: class not found: org.apache.ivy.ant.AntBuildTrigger in [] nor Ivy classloader
impossible to define new type: class not found: org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.IvyRepResolver in [] nor Ivy classloader
impossible to define new type: class not found: org.apache.ivy.plugins.signer.bouncycastle.OpenPGPSignatureGenerator in [] nor Ivy classloader
impossible to define new type: class not found: org.apache.ivy.plugins.conflict.RegexpConflictManager in [] nor Ivy classloader
impossible to define new type: class not found: org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.SFTPResolver in [] nor Ivy classloader
impossible to define new type: class not found: org.apache.ivy.osgi.updatesite.UpdateSiteResolver in [] nor Ivy classloader
impossible to define new type: class not found: org.apache.ivy.ant.AntCallTrigger in [] nor Ivy classloader
impossible to define new type: class not found: org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.MirroredURLResolver in [] nor Ivy classloader
impossible to define new type: class not found: org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.packager.PackagerResolver in [] nor Ivy classloader
impossible to define new type: class not found: org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.DualResolver in [] nor Ivy classloader
impossible to define new type: class not found: org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.VfsResolver in [] nor Ivy classloader
impossible to define new type: class not found: org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.JarResolver in [] nor Ivy classloader
impossible to define new type: class not found: org.apache.ivy.osgi.obr.OBRResolver in [] nor Ivy classloader
impossible to define glob matcher: org.apache.ivy.plugins.matcher.GlobPatternMatcher was not found.
setting 'jline.esc.timeout' to '0'
setting 'java.runtime.name' to 'Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment'
setting 'sun.boot.library.path' to 'C:\YYYY\JDK64\1.7.0.67\jre\bin'
setting 'java.vm.version' to '24.65-b04'
setting 'java.vm.vendor' to 'Oracle Corporation'
setting 'java.vendor.url' to 'http://java.oracle.com/'
setting 'path.separator' to ';'
setting 'java.vm.name' to 'Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM'
setting 'file.encoding.pkg' to 'sun.io'
setting 'user.country' to 'US'
setting 'user.script' to ''
setting 'sun.java.launcher' to 'SUN_STANDARD'
setting 'sun.os.patch.level' to 'Service Pack 1'
setting 'java.vm.specification.name' to 'Java Virtual Machine Specification'
setting 'user.dir' to 'C:\dev\workspace\manualsbt'
setting 'java.runtime.version' to '1.7.0_67-b01'
setting 'java.awt.graphicsenv' to 'sun.awt.Win32GraphicsEnvironment'
setting 'java.endorsed.dirs' to 'C:\YYYY\JDK64\1.7.0.67\jre\lib\endorsed'
setting 'os.arch' to 'amd64'
setting 'http.proxyUser' to 'me'
setting 'http.proxySet' to 'true'
setting 'java.io.tmpdir' to 'C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\'
setting 'line.separator' to '
'
setting 'java.vm.specification.vendor' to 'Oracle Corporation'
setting 'user.variant' to ''
setting 'os.name' to 'Windows 7'
setting 'sun.jnu.encoding' to 'Cp1252'
setting 'http.proxyPort' to '8080'
setting 'java.library.path' to 'C:\YYYY\JDK64\1.7.0.67\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\YYYY\JDK64\1.7.0.67\bin.....'
setting 'java.specification.name' to 'Java Platform API Specification'
setting 'java.class.version' to '51.0'
setting 'sun.management.compiler' to 'HotSpot 64-Bit Tiered Compilers'
setting 'http.proxyPassword' to '**********'
setting 'os.version' to '6.1'
setting 'user.home' to 'C:\Users\me'
setting 'user.timezone' to 'America/New_York'
setting 'java.awt.printerjob' to 'sun.awt.windows.WPrinterJob'
setting 'file.encoding' to 'Cp1252'
setting 'java.specification.version' to '1.7'
setting 'java.class.path' to 'C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\bin\sbt-launch.jar'
setting 'user.name' to 'me'
setting 'jline.shutdownhook' to 'false'
setting 'java.vm.specification.version' to '1.7'
setting 'sun.java.command' to 'xsbt.boot.Boot'
setting 'java.home' to 'C:\YYYY\JDK64\1.7.0.67\jre'
setting 'sun.arch.data.model' to '64'
setting 'user.language' to 'en'
setting 'java.specification.vendor' to 'Oracle Corporation'
setting 'awt.toolkit' to 'sun.awt.windows.WToolkit'
setting 'java.vm.info' to 'mixed mode'
setting 'java.version' to '1.7.0_67'
setting 'java.ext.dirs' to 'C:\YYYY\JDK64\1.7.0.67\jre\lib\ext;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\lib\ext'
setting 'http.proxyHost' to 'foobar.XXXXXXXX.net'
setting 'sun.boot.class.path' to 'C:\YYYY\JDK64\1.7.0.67\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\YYYY\JDK64\1.7.0.67\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\YYYY\JDK64\1.7.0.67\jre\lib\sunrsasign.jar;C:\YYYY\JDK64\1.7.0.67\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\YYYY\JDK64\1.7.0.67\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\YYYY\JDK64\1.7.0.67\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\YYYY\JDK64\1.7.0.67\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\YYYY\JDK64\1.7.0.67\jre\classes'
setting 'java.vendor' to 'Oracle Corporation'
setting 'file.separator' to '\'
setting 'java.vendor.url.bug' to 'http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/'
setting 'sun.io.unicode.encoding' to 'UnicodeLittle'
setting 'sun.cpu.endian' to 'little'
setting 'sun.desktop' to 'windows'
setting 'sun.cpu.isalist' to 'amd64'
setting 'ivy.default.ivy.user.dir' to 'C:\Users\me\.ivy2'
setting 'ivy.home' to 'C:\Users\me\.ivy2'
setting 'ivy.cache.dir' to 'C:\Users\me\.ivy2\cache'
no default cache defined: set to C:\Users\me\.ivy2\cache
setting 'ivy.checksums' to 'sha1,md5'
setting 'ivy.basedir' to 'C:\Users\me\.sbt\boot'
setting 'basedir' to 'C:\Users\me\.sbt\boot'
:: resolving dependencies :: org.scala-sbt#boot-app;1.0
    confs: [default]
    validate = true
    refresh = false
resolving dependencies for configuration 'default'
== resolving dependencies for org.scala-sbt#boot-app;1.0 [default]
loadData of org.scala-sbt#boot-app;1.0 of rootConf=default
== resolving dependencies org.scala-sbt#boot-app;1.0->org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.13.5 [default->default(compile)]
loadData of org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.13.5 of rootConf=default
    using redefined-public to resolve org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.13.5
redefined-public: Checking cache for: dependency: org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.13.5 {default=[default(compile)]}
redefined-public: no namespace defined: using system
    no ivy file in cache for org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.13.5: tried C:\Users\me\.ivy2\cache\org.scala-sbt\sbt\ivy-0.13.5.xml
redefined-public: no latest strategy defined: using default
local: no namespace defined: using system
    no ivy file in cache for org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.13.5: tried C:\Users\me\.ivy2\cache\org.scala-sbt\sbt\ivy-0.13.5.xml
     trying C:\Users\me\.ivy2\local\org.scala-sbt\sbt\0.13.5\ivys\ivy.xml
        tried C:\Users\me\.ivy2\local\org.scala-sbt\sbt\0.13.5\ivys\ivy.xml
    local: resource not reachable for org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.13.5: res=C:\Users\me\.ivy2\local\org.scala-sbt\sbt\0.13.5\ivys\ivy.xml
     trying C:\Users\me\.ivy2\local\org.scala-sbt\sbt\0.13.5\jars\sbt.jar
        tried C:\Users\me\.ivy2\local\org.scala-sbt\sbt\0.13.5\jars\sbt.jar
    local: resource not reachable for org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.13.5: res=C:\Users\me\.ivy2\local\org.scala-sbt\sbt\0.13.5\jars\sbt.jar
    local: no ivy file nor artifact found for org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.13.5
XXXivy: no namespace defined: using system
    no ivy file in cache for org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.13.5: tried C:\Users\me\.ivy2\cache\org.scala-sbt\sbt\ivy-0.13.5.xml
     trying https://repo.XXXXXXXX.net/maven/content/repositories/XXXX-IVY-HOSTED-OS/org/scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.5/sbt-0.13.5.pom
        tried https://repo.XXXXXXXX.net/maven/content/repositories/XXXX-IVY-HOSTED-OS/org/scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.5/sbt-0.13.5.pom
HTTP response status: 404 url=https://repo.XXXXXXXX.net/maven/content/repositories/XXXX-IVY-HOSTED-OS/org/scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.5/sbt-0.13.5.pom
CLIENT ERROR: Not Found url=https://repo.XXXXXXXX.net/maven/content/repositories/XXXX-IVY-HOSTED-OS/org/scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.5/sbt-0.13.5.pom
    XXXivy: resource not reachable for org/scala-sbt#sbt;0.13.5: res=https://repo.XXXXXXXX.net/maven/content/repositories/XXXX-IVY-HOSTED-OS/org/scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.5/sbt-0.13.5.pom
     trying https://repo.XXXXXXXX.net/maven/content/repositories/XXXX-IVY-HOSTED-OS/org/scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.5/sbt-0.13.5.jar
        tried https://repo.XXXXXXXX.net/maven/content/repositories/XXXX-IVY-HOSTED-OS/org/scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.5/sbt-0.13.5.jar
    XXXivy: no ivy file found for org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.13.5: using default data
    checking org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.13.5[default] from XXXivy against [none]
    module revision kept as first found: org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.13.5[default] from XXXivy
nexus: no namespace defined: using system
Entry is found in the ModuleDescriptorCache : C:\Users\me\.ivy2\cache\org.scala-sbt\sbt\ivy-0.13.5.xml
    resolver not found: null => trying to use the one configured for org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.13.5
    configured resolver found for org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.13.5: redefined-public: saving this data
    found ivy file in cache for org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.13.5 (resolved by redefined-public): C:\Users\me\.ivy2\cache\org.scala-sbt\sbt\ivy-0.13.5.xml
    nexus: found revision in cache: org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.13.5 (resolved by redefined-public): but it's a default one, maybe we can find a better one
     trying https://repo.XXXXXXXX.net/maven/content/groups/XXXX-public/org/scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.5/sbt-0.13.5.pom
        tried https://repo.XXXXXXXX.net/maven/content/groups/XXXX-public/org/scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.5/sbt-0.13.5.pom
HTTP response status: 404 url=https://repo.XXXXXXXX.net/maven/content/groups/XXXX-public/org/scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.5/sbt-0.13.5.pom
CLIENT ERROR: Not Found url=https://repo.XXXXXXXX.net/maven/content/groups/XXXX-public/org/scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.5/sbt-0.13.5.pom
    nexus: resource not reachable for org/scala-sbt#sbt;0.13.5: res=https://repo.XXXXXXXX.net/maven/content/groups/XXXX-public/org/scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.5/sbt-0.13.5.pom
     trying https://repo.XXXXXXXX.net/maven/content/groups/XXXX-public/org/scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.5/sbt-0.13.5.jar
        tried https://repo.XXXXXXXX.net/maven/content/groups/XXXX-public/org/scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.5/sbt-0.13.5.jar
    nexus: no ivy file found for org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.13.5: using default data
    checking org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.13.5[default] from nexus against org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.13.5[default] from XXXivy
nexus: no latest strategy defined: using default
    module revision discarded as older: org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.13.5[default] from nexus
    found org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.13.5 in XXXivy
Nbr of module to sort : 1
Sort dependencies of : org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.13.5 / Number of dependencies = 0
Sort done for : org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.13.5
storing dependency org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.13.5 in props
    resolved ivy file produced in cache
:: downloading artifacts ::
     trying https://repo.XXXXXXXX.net/maven/content/repositories/XXXX-IVY-HOSTED-OS/org/scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.5/sbt-0.13.5.jar
        tried https://repo.XXXXXXXX.net/maven/content/repositories/XXXX-IVY-HOSTED-OS/org/scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.5/sbt-0.13.5.jar
downloading https://repo.XXXXXXXX.net/maven/content/repositories/XXXX-IVY-HOSTED-OS/org/scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.5/sbt-0.13.5.jar ...
    XXXivy: downloading https://repo.XXXXXXXX.net/maven/content/repositories/XXXX-IVY-HOSTED-OS/org/scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.5/sbt-0.13.5.jar
        to C:\Users\me\.ivy2\cache\org.scala-sbt\sbt\jars\sbt-0.13.5.jar.part
HTTP response status: 404 url=https://repo.XXXXXXXX.net/maven/content/repositories/XXXX-IVY-HOSTED-OS/org/scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.5/sbt-0.13.5.jar.sha1
CLIENT ERROR: Not Found url=https://repo.XXXXXXXX.net/maven/content/repositories/XXXX-IVY-HOSTED-OS/org/scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.5/sbt-0.13.5.jar.sha1
HTTP response status: 404 url=https://repo.XXXXXXXX.net/maven/content/repositories/XXXX-IVY-HOSTED-OS/org/scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.5/sbt-0.13.5.jar.md5
CLIENT ERROR: Not Found url=https://repo.XXXXXXXX.net/maven/content/repositories/XXXX-IVY-HOSTED-OS/org/scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.5/sbt-0.13.5.jar.md5
    [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.13.5!sbt.jar (418ms)
:: resolution report :: resolve 1119ms :: artifacts dl 420ms
Nbr of module to sort : 1
Sort dependencies of : org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.13.5 / Number of dependencies = 0
Sort done for : org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.13.5
    report for org.scala-sbt#boot-app;1.0 default produced in C:\Users\me\.sbt\boot\resolution-cache\org.scala-sbt-boot-app-default.xml
    resolve done (1119ms resolve - 420ms download)
:: retrieving :: org.scala-sbt#boot-app
    checkUpToDate=true
post 1.3 ivy file: using exact as default matcher
no explicit confs given for retrieve, using ivy file: file:/C:/Users/me/.sbt/boot/resolution-cache/resolved-org.scala-sbt-boot-app-1.0.xml
    confs: [default]
    retrieving C:\Users\me\.ivy2\cache\org.scala-sbt\sbt\jars\sbt-0.13.5.jar
        to C:\Users\me\.sbt\boot\other\org.scala-sbt\sbt\0.13.5\sbt-0.13.5.jar
    1 artifacts copied, 0 already retrieved (20kB/20ms)
    retrieve done (20ms)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem. My repositories file did not correctly point to an Ivy repository. Once I fixed it, everything worked like a charm.

This is what my repositories file looks like now:

```
[repositories]
  local
  ivy: https://repo.xxxxxxxx.net/maven/content/repositories/groups/xxxx-ivy-public/, [organization]/[module]/(scala_[scalaVersion]/)(sbt_[sbtVersion]/)[revision]/[type]s/[artifact](-[classifier]).[ext]IVY-HOSTED-OS/
  nexus: https://repo.xxxxxxxx.net/maven/content/groups/xxxx-public/
```